# Trying to make vertical tab more subtle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

As you can see in the picture, I'm trying to make a vertical tab like it. I have posted the code on jsfiddle, would appreciate if someone help me with the alignment of the columns where two columns on top and two on bottom and how to write the descriptions on the columns. Also the image in the columns expand a little when you hover over them.
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}



/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid deepskyblue;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    display: block;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: white;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
color: white;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;

    width: 70%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}
.headd{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
     border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    }

    .right .left-col div, .right .right-col div{
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: block;
    height: 65px;
    width: 330px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 5px 5px;
 } 
    .all{background-color: deepskyblue;
    height: 400px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container all">
<p>Events</p>

<div class="tab">

    <div class="headd"><p> 21 January - 23 January</p></div>

  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDate(event, '11')" id="defaultOpen">21 January</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDate(event, '22')">22 January</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDate(event, '33')">23 January</button>
</div>

<div id="11" class="tabcontent">
  <div class="right">

        <div class="left-col">  
          <div class="">
              Play
          </div>
          <div class="">
              Play
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-col">
          <div class="">
              Play
          </div>
          <div class="">
              Play
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

<div id="22" class="tabcontent">
 <div class="right">

        <div class="left-col">  
          <div class="">
              Run
          </div>
          <div class="">
              Run
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-col">
          <div class="">
              Run
          </div>
          <div class="">
              Run
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
</div>

<div id="33" class="tabcontent">
 <div class="right">

        <div class="left-col">  
          <div class="">
              Game
          </div>
          <div class="">
              Game
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-col">
          <div class="">
              Game
          </div>
          <div class="">
              Game
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function openDate(evt, dateName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(dateName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the jsfiddle of what I tried so far
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jbgvemot/)

Comment: why are not you using bootstrap or foundation ?

Comment: @mzh There is no obligation to use a framework

Comment: @ovokuro I know but the framework is there always to have a standard of what you develop.

Comment: https://codepen.io/IamManchanda/pen/eWKLdX?editors=1000 
have a look on it.

Comment: i want the exact thing as in the image.. i'm not sure how to do it. i tried bootstrap but couldn't get it done..